# How to use trigger in Datagrip?

Tags: mysql, database, datagrip

I want to learn how to insert a record when my modify is nonfeasible.And I want to create a trigger like that.But when I use Datagrip 2022.2,I don't know how.Anyone can help me?

I tried to google and find the official document,and there's no usage about trigger.

Comment: Create needed trigger in the same way as for any other stored object (view, UDF, SP, EP...)

Comment: You need to create a trigger in the database, not in the DataGrip